# Dynamic query, parameters not working for where in

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, where-in

I am working with dynamic queries on oracle and when I pass the string parameter for where in condition, its not working.

```
for x in (
            SELECT DISTINCT column_id
            FROM table
            WHERE column_id in (in_column_ids)          
            /* WHERE column_id in (15,16,17) =>works */
            /* => in_column_ids is a varchar type which 
                  holds comma separated value */
            and column_title=in_column_title /* works */
    )
```

Here, if I keep the values directly on that in_column_ids, the query works.
But, the value that is being passed as parameter doesn't seem to work for `where in`.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you have to splits comma delimited variable using [regexp_substr](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=508). Your query should be like this:

```
for x in (
            SELECT DISTINCT column_id
            FROM table
            WHERE column_id in (
            SELECT DISTINCT regexp_substr(in_column_ids,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY regexp_substr(in_column_ids, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
            )          
            /* WHERE column_id in (15,16,17) =>works */
            /* => in_column_ids is a varchar type which 
                  holds comma separated value */
            and column_title=in_column_title /* works */
    )
```

Check out ***[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96ca8/2)***